# My google_map is not reacting after switching between tabs in a shiny dashboard

Tags: r, shiny, sidebar, googleway

I have a google map that shows markers whenever I click on the map. This map is located at one tab in my shiny dashboard. I also have there a table that shows the tabulated info of the markers.

So far, so good.

The problem appears when I switch to a any different tab and then I get back to the google map tab. The maps is not reacting, the markers are not updating despite the information on the table is. So, the problem is on the map itself.

Is there a way to keep, I don't know, active the map even if I'm in different tab, or the map refresh when I get back to the tab?

This is my sidebar

```
        sidebar<-dashboardSidebar(
        fluidRow(column(width = 12,
        fluidRow(column(width = 12,
          sidebarMenu(
            id = "sidebar",
            menuItem("Inicio", tabName="BVND"),
            menuItem("Localizador", tabName="LOC"),
            menuItem("Homologación", tabName="HOM")

          )))
        )
```

Inside the "Localizador" is where I call the map: google_mapOutput(outputId = "map",height = 600).

and in the output I have

```
         google_map(key = map_key
                            ,location = c(avia[2], avia[1],"red")
                            ,data=distancia2
                            ,zoom = 18
                            ,height = 1500

             ) %>%
               add_markers(lat="latitud"
                           ,lon="longitud"
                                    ,title ="title"
                           ,info_window="info_window"
                           ,close_info_window=TRUE
                           ,marker_icon = "icon" 
               )
```

I tried the updatetabitems, google_map_update, as reactives/observe in my output or the server itself

Comment: Please post a fully reproducible example we can run, including the runApp() and all the library() calls.

Comment: at the moment, what I found is that my google_mapOutput is not refreshing when I get back to the tab, I think I need that output to refresh or reload when I get back to my map tab

Comment: please post the code for the entire shinyapp in your question for us to reproduce the issue. This should include the server and ui calls.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by "fragmenting" the observe. 
The action is that the map updates whenever I click on it, and it wasn't doing it if I went to a different section of the app. 
[image: map and sections]

I rewrote the "click on map" action by using an observe containing google_map_update.

```
google_map_update( "map"
                   ,session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain()
) %>%
  clear_markers(    ) %>%
  clear_polygons()

google_map_update( "map"
                   ,session = shiny::getDefaultReactiveDomain()
) %>%
  add_markers(data = data
              ,lat="latitud"
              ,lon="longitud"
              ,title ="title"
              ,info_window="info_window"
              ,close_info_window=TRUE
              ,marker_icon = "icon" 
  )
```

you have to be careful. For some reason in another action, the add_markers cause problems inside an observeEvent. So you might want to avoid or test the add_markers in an map update.

(Sorry I didn't wrote the example of the problem, it's kind of a big project and didn't have time to make a slim version of it. I hope at least it helps to another fellow with same or similar issues)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post the solution. It works, you saved my day.